# Handle bash variable that may include dollar sign?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, character

I have a script that accepts user input which may contain special characters.  I run that variable through a sed recipe that will find and escape special characters, but if the variable contains a '$' the output is truncated.  How can I automagically escape any dollar sign that may appear in the variable?  Or do I just have to echo back a message, "If there's a dollar sign you must prepend a backslash to it"?

Comment: How is your script getting user input?

Comment: Please show just enough code to reproduce the issue that you have, including both how you get the input and how your want to use the escaped string.

Comment: You have the wrong approach since you cannot in general use a sed script to escape "special characters" since the meaning of "special" characters is context-sensitive and you need to set aside at least 1 "special" char for sed to use as it's delimiter. Post some sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sample file:

```
$ cat file.txt
Foo
teste $var lorem ipsum
$foo bar $z
Bar
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p 'Type search pattern: ' pattern
sed -n '/'"${pattern}"'/ p' < file.txt
```

Now if you do `chmod u+x script` and then:

```
$ ./script
Type search pattern: $var
teste $var lorem ipsum
```

Although extremely simple, it works. Are you properly quoting stuff?

Comment: Try it with user input of `a/b` and you'll get a cryptic error message like `sed: can't find label for jump to `/'`. You simply can't do this with sed.

Comment: If I do `sed -n '\:'"${pattern}"': p' < file.txt` it seems to work in GNU Sed 4.2.2. The input I tried was `a/b`.

Comment: Now try your new sed command with user input of `a:b` and you'll get `sed: can't find label for jump to ':'`. Ad infinitum... The problem is the OP wants to treat the input as a string (i.e. all literal characters) but sed does not support strings at all and no matter how you try to figure out what needs to be escaped to make sed try to NOT treat the regexp it's processing as a regexp, there's always exceptions. Just use a tool like fgrep or awk that have string handling functionaity.

Comment: @EdMorton, The question seems to concern the dollar sign, though. Anyway, it seems the person who posted didn't even read this post anymore, neither has he posted some sample code or input anyway. Still, you are right. No mater what delimiter is used, it is always possible to break it.